# How can you tell if one div tag/element is over another?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Working on a drag and drop feature and I would like to know/have an opinion on how you can tell if an element, in this case a div tag, is position (via the drag) over another element?

Thanks, R.

Comment: How did this end? I'm using Jquery, and like to use it for a check like this!

Answer (score 1):

You should look into a framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to handle things like this easily, however if you want to learn exactly how it works, [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/dragdrop.html) has a good tutorial on drag and drop (probably more information then you want).

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing straight Javascript, or using an external library that already implements drag-n-drop, like [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/)?